# Posting on Twitter an image via API request

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, twitter, upload

I'm trying to make posts on Twitter via API. I want the user to fill out a form that when submitted makes a post on twitter with the form info, I can do that easily,

```js
let tweet = request.body.text + '\n' + request.body.hashtags;
T.post('statuses/update', {
    status: tweet
}, function(err, data, response) {
    console.log(data)
    created_at = data.created_at;
    post_id = data.id_str;
    hashtags = request.body.hashtags
    user = data.user.name;
    screen_name = data.user.screen_name;
    text = request.body.text;

    let obj = {
        post_id: post_id,
        created_at: created_at,
        text: text,
        hashtags: hashtags,
        screen_name: screen_name,
        user: user
    }
    let posts = []
    posts.push(obj)
    TwitterModel.TwitterModel.insertMany(obj, (error, docs) => {
        if (error) return resp.status(MESSAGES.error.e0.http).send(error);
        return resp.render('back-office.ejs');
    });
})
```

this works fine,
but now I want to give the user the ability to add an image and for that, I need to use this code here.

```js
 //
 // post a tweet with media
 //
 var b64content = fs.readFileSync('/path/to/img', {
     encoding: 'base64'
 })

 // first we must post the media to Twitter
 T.post('media/upload', {
     media_data: b64content
 }, function(err, data, response) {
     // now we can assign alt text to the media, for use by screen readers and
     // other text-based presentations and interpreters
     var mediaIdStr = data.media_id_string
     var altText = "Small flowers in a planter on a sunny balcony, blossoming."
     var meta_params = {
         media_id: mediaIdStr,
         alt_text: {
             text: altText
         }
     }

     T.post('media/metadata/create', meta_params, function(err, data, response) {
         if (!err) {
             // now we can reference the media and post a tweet (media will attach to the tweet)
             var params = {
                 status: 'loving life #nofilter',
                 media_ids: [mediaIdStr]
             }

             T.post('statuses/update', params, function(err, data, response) {
                 console.log(data)
             })
         }
     })
 })
```

For this to work I need to get the relative path to the image which I don't know how to do, the user uploads the image via the (input type="file").
I believe there must be a really easy way to get the relative path that I don't know about but maybe someone can tell me.
I am currently trying to use Firebase Storage but it doesn't seem possible to use that, I am able to store the image on Firebase but I have no idea how to actually use that in the API request.
PS: I am using the Twit NPM module to post on twitter